# Rails keeps stating error when trying to create scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

I'm needing to generate a scaffold for my rails app, but the system keeps stating a long error involving actionpack. Problem is, actionpack is tied to many different parts of the app. If I delete it, the entire app and its files will not work. Here is the error message:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get': uninitialized constant User (NameError)
```

How can I fix this problem to generate the scaffold?

Comment: please, write the command, that you trying to execute

Comment: the command is "rails generate scaffold [Generate object], more specifically,

Comment: "rails generate scaffold member"

Comment: I have tried using just 'rails generate controller member', but that just returns the error message.

Comment: `uninitialized constant User (NameError)` - somewhere in your code you are referencing a `User` class, but there is not one defined? That is my guess based on the error message - or maybe you have a user.rb file with no `User` class defined in it?

Comment: No good. I've search all of the files within the application, and there are no files which contain a User class in the first place. If there are, they aren't based on a user.rb file.

Comment: Plus, it says that the actionpack gem is returning a user class error. Would uninstalling the gem do something that could fix this?

Comment: ok, now its saying that its activesupport. I'm not sure if an error involving this has been documented, but it now shows the error for that.

Comment: active support is a major component of the rails framework - this error is most likely occurring while active support is booting up the application, it is generating classes based on file names, etc... are you sure you don't have a `user.rb` file in your project?